# One to Many Join in SQLBrite

Tags: android, sqlbrite

Say I have three SQLite tables `week`, `day`, `event`.

A `week` entry can have multiple `day` child entries which in turn can have multiple `event` child entries.

To fetch a whole `week` entity with associated kids to be displayed in a `TableLayout` I would usually do the following query:

`SELECT * FROM week JOIN day on week.id = day.week_id JOIN event on day.id = event.day_id WHERE week.id=foo`

This would return a cursor I could easily parse.

**What is the equivalent of this flow in SQLBrite?**

I have to map the resulting observable of `db.createQuery` to either `mapToList` or `mapToOne` which is kind of tricky to grasp. I tried mapping to one and then parsing the cursor in a subscriber but I got a *cursor has multiple lines* exception. Mapping to a list is somehow unnatural since I only expect one `week` entry at the end.

What am I missing? :)
Thanks!